# apollo useQuery when does query get made?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

We can read the following in Apollo docs..

> By default, the useQuery hook checks the Apollo Client cache to see if
> all the data you requested is already available locally. If all data
> is available locally, useQuery returns that data and doesn't query
> your GraphQL server. This cache-first policy is Apollo Client's
> default fetch policy.

Let's say I have a page where I load all the books that people have added. Let's say userA is looking at this screen. `userB` now added a new one.

Questions:

- If `userA` refreshes the page, would he/she see the new book added ? would the query be made ?
- I really don't get what apollo means `if all data is available locally`. How can Apollo know if all data is already available ? someone could have added it meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set it to use the Apollo cache, User A will not hear about User B's new book by default. There are a few ways to address this:

1. Poll the server every x minutes
2. Set up a subscription to the server
3. Notify the front end that updates are available through a separate subscription

Comment: Thanks for answering. I quite don't understand what 2&3 means. and also, if I use `network-only` , I guess that's way 4 of achieving it.

Comment: Yeah, you can use network-only while you are developing, but it doesn't scale well in production. 

Here's the subscriptions docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/

I wouldn't usually do that though. I do 1 or 3. The way 3 works is, if you had, say a small group (say 2-50 users) sharing a document, say a Book, then when one use updates it, you could send a little message to the other people who share that document, to let them know an update is available.  Then the front end can react to that notification, invalidate the cache and requery.

Comment: There are a few ways to do that subscription in #3. You could use Websockets. Or, for example, your backend can emit a PubSub event, and that can be consumed by a separate service that your front end subscribes to. But for most cases, just set up polling every few minutes, and then if you want to optimize you can work on only pulling records that have changed after the last poll.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Here is my insight.  Sometimes, I really do need that when one user updates something, when another one refreshes the page, he should see the update.  For sure, websockets is good, but no time for that... Problem with polling every x minutes is that when user refreshes the page, he won't see the changes immediatelly, until `x` minutes have passed. That's the downside...

Comment: and one more question: I guess, `by default, the useQuery hook checks the Apollo Client cache to see if all the data you requested is already available locally.`. I guess, it means that apollo checks if the data is cached on the url you enter again. if that url contains the data in cache, then it will return from there. Right?

Comment: If it can infer that it has all the objects that would be responsive to your query, that's what it returns. But it does not know if things changed on the backend since the query. There's a nice, normalized cache, so if you got some child records in one query, say me { userId, userName, userBooks { bookId, bookName} } then it can use those Books  object from the cache to fulfill other queries.